# Кто-нибудь читал эту книгу?

Tags: другое

**[Самый полный курс русского языка.  Адамчик Н.В.](http://www.alleng.ru/d/rusl/rusl342.htm)** - Пособие написано в соответствии с программой по русскому языку, действующей в современной школе. Теоретический материал изложен полно, логично и доступно, проиллюстрирован значительным количеством примеров. Пособие ориентировано на тех, кто хочет углубленно изучать русский язык. Оно содержит развернутый (по сравнению со школьными учебниками) теоретический материал, охватывающий все разделы современного языка. Основное назначение книги - помочь в осознании вопросов теории, развить способность самостоятельно анализировать различные явления русского языка, а также разобраться в сложных вопросах при подготовке к тестированию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто-нибудь читал.

Comment: Кстати, о синтаксисе. Gramota.ru рекомендует для ликбеза книгу Литневской "Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников": http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php

Comment: Здравствуйте! Может, мне стоить сначала прочитать вот эту книгу, которая очень неплохо рассказывает об основах? Как Вы её оцените? Почему Розенталь является самым уважаемым автором?

http://www.multsoft.ru/book/3414-sovremennyy-russkiy-yazyk-d-e-rozental-i-b-golub-m-a-telenkova.html

Comment: Ответила в основном окне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не читала, но просмотрела некоторые темы. Книга как книга. Хорошая книга. Она и не может быть плохой, учитывая, что автор ее не столько писал, сколько компилировал. Ведь правила не сочинишь, они уже сформулированы.

Достоинство издания: претензия на полноту и универсальность, реализованная благодаря сокращению количества примеров, некоторых формулировок, отдельных правил и целых тем.

Недостаток: отсутствие многих тем практической стилистики, которые хорошо освещены у Розенталя и необходимы тому, кто работает с текстами.

Можно заниматься и по этой книге. Но чтобы все это запомнить, надо применять знания на практике. Тогда вы поймете, какие из них полезные, а какие просто заполняют тематические ниши в учебнике.

ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ О СИНТАКСИСЕ

Глубочайшие знания тут не нужны. Надо отличать подлежащее от сказуемого, придаточное предложение от однородных членов, знать деепричастный оборот и фразеологизм. Правила пунктуации сформулированы для общего пользования, а значит, интуитивно понятны, тем более что проиллюстрированы множеством примеров. У нас целый отдел корректоров без филологического образования, на слово "синтаксис" не реагируют, а работают хорошо, потому что читают Розенталя. Справитесь.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Конечно, можно читать и "Современный русский язык" Розенталя как базовую книгу. Но орфографию, пунктуацию и стилистику всё равно учить по *Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке*.

Розенталь лучше других авторов, потому что он гений. Он был самым активным участником реформы русского языка 1956 года, сформулировал правила орфографии и пунктуации, которыми мы пользуемся сейчас, основал новую дисциплину - практическую стилистику, написал самые полные учебники и справочники для издательских работников. Здесь можете почитать статью о Розентале со ссылками для скачивания 20 его книг: http://www.media-school.com.ua/2013/07/blog-post_10.html

Самый полный учебник пунктуации (полнее не бывает):

*Розенталь Д. Э. **Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация***.

Как дополнение к ней можно использовать *Былинский К. И., Розенталь Д. Э. **Трудные случаи пунктуации***.

Есть у него и учебники для школьников:

*Розенталь Д. Э. **Пособие по русскому языку для поступающих в вузы***.

*Розенталь Д. Э. **Русский язык: Учебное пособие для школьников старших классов и поступающих в вузы***.

И масса занимательных книг о русском языке:

*Голуб И. Б., Розенталь Д. Э. **Занимательная стилистика**.

Голуб И. Б., Розенталь Д. Э. **Книга о хорошей речи**.

Иванова В. А., Потиха З. А., Розенталь Д. Э. **Занимательно о русском языке**.

*Розенталь Д. Э. **А как лучше сказать?***

Эти книги и другие можно скачать со страниц:

http://www.media-school.com.ua/2013/07/blog-post_10.html

http://www.media-school.com.ua/p/blog-page_12.html

Если ссылки устарели или книги не откроются, пишите мне на tat-machin@ukr.net

Comment: А где эту практику взять? Если читать теорию в этом пособии, то как практиковаться?

Comment: Исправлять ошибки в реальных текстах. И задавать самому себе как можно больше вопросов. Например, репку тянул дедка и бабка или тянули? Не читал этой книги или не читал эту книгу? Вопросы появятся - не сомневайтесь. А запомните вы только те ответы, которые найдете сами. Просто читать эту книгу - непродуктивно: слишком много информации для дезориентированного мозга. Очень полезно сравнивать сырые тексты и отредактированные профессионалами. На сайтах, предлагающих услуги корректирования и редактирования, есть образцы - что было и что стало.

Comment: Можно внедриться в местную газету - прийти и попросить тексты для сравнения, объяснить, что мечтаете стать литредактором-корректором, - думаю, это растрогает тетеньку.  А деньги больше не тратьте. Одно дело - если вам нужно подготовиться к экзамену и быстро получить массу бесполезной для жизни информации, и другое - долгосрочное развитие грамотности. Тут вас никто не научит, кроме Розенталя и Gramota.ru. Потому что грамотные остались только среди корректоров, которые как раз и учатся по этим источникам. Вообще в этом деле главное - самообразование.

Comment: Если вы в состоянии сами освоить эту информацию - эта профессия для вас. Если никак не идет - плюньте: зарплаты маленькие, а знания нужны огромные. Обязательно пользуйтесь Gramota.ru - это очень хороший сайт Академии наук с архивом вопросов и ответов, там же можно и самому задавать вопросы. Если понадобится консультация, как пользоваться, - пишите.  Что касается Адамчика, то разделы "Орфография" и "Пунктуация" взяты полностью из Розенталя, потому что Розенталь все эти правила сформулировал.

Comment: Его учебник самый полный и включает также практическую стилистику, которую именно Розенталь и создал как дисциплину. В его книге этот раздел называется "Литературное редактирование" - посмотрите, не помешает.  Если честно, у Адамчика много такого, что в работе не пригодится. Можно, конечно, знать, что речь должна быть точной, логичной и выразительной, а дальше что? Зачем вам знать, как устроен речевой аппарат? Вы же не будете логопедом? Из "Графики" нужно выучить только алфавит, чтобы быстро находить слово в бумажном словаре.

Comment: Без орфоэпии тоже можно прожить. Морфология способна доконать любого - пользуйтесь этим разделом, если понадобится уточнить какой-то термин, без которого правило непонятно. По большому счеты вам нужны орфография, пунктуация и практическая стилистика - всё есть у Розенталя. Можете сравнить с Адамчиком.

Comment: Я плохо знаю синтаксис. Как я буду учить это без знания синтаксиса?